# When installing SSIS Projects from extensions, an error pops up that certain processes are running, how do I get past that?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to install SQL Server Integration Services Project into my Visual Studio 2019 tool, and I receive an error message listing several processes running, impeding proceeding with the load. I went to Task Manager and I do not see these processes running. How do I get past this error?

Comment: Solution: Keeping the error open, open Task Manager go to -more details - click on the Detail tab and search for the processes running, which are listed in the pop error box. Right click on them and end task. After finding them, and ending the tasks, I was able to proceed with the download. **Note that killing one process did kill some of the others thus I didn't find all the listed processes, but that was fine.**

Comment: Comments aren't for solutions.